# Is DxO Optics better than Lightroom, or vice versa?

Tags: software, lightroom, dxo-optics

My guess is that they have some features in common, they have some differences too, but actually they are almost the same quality level.

Are there reason to say one is better than the other or is most of all a matter of personal taste and needs?

Comment: Quick suggestion: why not download the demos for both programs and see what works better for you?

Comment: Or reword the question to something like, "What are the differences between using DxO Optics or Lightroom? For what particular tasks is one more suited than the other?"

Comment: DxO has very bad UI (very inconvenient, unresponsive), sometimes it crashes as well, but as far as I know it has some nice processing utilities, especially distortion correction. Also, Lightroom by default produces crappy colors (not realistic color reproduction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that they are different. Lightroom offers more bang for the buck, better detail and contrast, and better workflow, but there are situations where DxO shines. This review summarizes it well.

http://corrosphotoblog.blogspot.com/2012/03/adobe-lightroom-4-vs-dxo-optics-pro-7.html